# Easy goodness of fit tests when using svyolr package (ordered logit regression on complex survey data)?

Tags: r, goodness-of-fit, ordered-logit, pseudo-r-squared

for a uni project I am running an ordered logit regression on survey data, using the svyolr package in R. I am looking to report some sort of goodness of fit for the model but am struggling to find any easy to run tests that work with the svyolr package. Some sort of pseudo R squared (I am aware of the shortcomings but would suffice for this sort of uni project) would be ideal, but lots of out the box tests / functions for doing so in R don't appear to work with the svyolr package. Can anyone help? Thank you.